# php how to generate dynamic database connection in for loop in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i am new to working in php, i am work on how to  alter table  dynamically in database through coding in php

database like this,

database name : data_switch

table name - data

```
 did   dataname  host  dbuser   dbpwd   dbname
 1     abc      local  root    root     abc_db   // here dataname create new database, when register new dataname
 2     pqr      ubuntu root    passwd   pqr_db
```

php code below:

```
<?php
        $dsn = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "passwd";


        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dsn;dbname=data_switch", $username, $password);
      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        foreach ($db->query("select * from data") as $row)
        {
           $dataname = $row['dataname'];
           $host = $row['host'];
           $dbuser = $row['dbuser'];
           $dbpwd = $row['dbpwd'];
           $dbname = $row['dbname'];

          $connection_array['data1'][] = array(

              'dataname' => $dataname,
              'host' => $host,
              'dbuser' => $dbuser,
              'dbpwd' => $dbpwd,
              'dbname' => $dbname
           );

        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($connection_array);

       $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpwd);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   // here all dataname find but i dont know how to generate dataname's own connection. dynamically

?>
```

i am getting all dataname in loop but i am not able to dynamically diffrent connection,i am register new dataname in form as like **abc** then it create a new database dynamically, but when i am alter the table i am not getting how to connection dynamically on each dataname's host,dbname,dbpwd through each own dataname.

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: This is highly unorthodox, creating databases in a dynamic manner, never seen such thing...

Comment: About your specific question: you need to assign the database connection you get back from the `new PDO()` call to _different_ variables. Otherwise you always replace the prior one just as with wech other variable. Maybe you want to store the objects in an array... But as said: what you attempts is "strange"...

Comment: can u understand my question ?? what i say  @arkascha

Comment: I thought I did understand your question. That is why I posted these comments. Sorry if you have the impression that is not the case.

Comment: sorry @arkascha,  i store object bt the connection string in for loop inside writing ??

Comment: I don't think you should be using `$db` as the variable for the dynamic database connection inside your loop **because it is still being used by your** `foreach ($db->query())`.

Comment: hmm, please tell me the  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpwd);
           $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); it write inside loop or not ??   @MrGlass

Comment: @parasprajapati, yes, that should have addressed that specific issue. Unfortunately it doesn't fix your overall problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but it came up in a search as a possible relation to a question I had.

I have a script doing very similar to what is being asked. You need to place your connections in a dynamic variable.

eg.

I have a list of branches and their respective database connection details in an array called $branchDcom. I can make calls to all my branches without closing connections and opening all the time.

I have a connection function that connects to a database with the sent values in the function conn_dcom_branch('your_server', 'your_db', 'your_username', 'your_password')

The following creates connections to all databases.

```
$connection = array();
foreach ($branchDcom as $key => $value) {
    $branch = $value['Name'];
    if (!is_resource($connections[$branch]['conn'])) {
        ${'connection_'.$branch} = conn_dcom_branch($value['server'], $value['db'], $value['username'], $value['password']);
        ${'connection_'.$branch.'_db'} = $value['db'];
    }
}
```

This gives me an array of all branch connections and their respective database names.

To use just enter in the branch name and it will use that connection:

```
$branch = 'select_name';
$query = "
    SELECT 
        your_field
    FROM 
         [".${'connection_'.$branch.'_db'}."].['table_name'] 
";
$rs = ${'connection_'.$branch}->execute($query);
```

This may help someone